# How to use functional interfaces one afther the other

Tags: java

Firstly sorry for my English because it isn't good but I have problem with functional interfaces...

I have Hello class, main method:

```
Function <String, List<String>> functionA;
Function <<List<String>, String> functionB;
Function <String, List<Integer>> functionC;
Function <List<Integer>, Integer> functionD;
```

and after that:

```
Execute execute = new Execute(pathToFile);

List<Integer> integerList = execute.make(functionA);
Integer integer1 = execute.make(functionA, functionB);
List<String> stringList = execute.make(functionA, functionB, functionC);
Integer integer2 = execute.make(functionA, functionB, functionC, functionD);
```

Make is method in Execute class.
In that method I should run tab of functions. For example: functionB is making his body from result of functionA, function C is making his body from result of functionB... functionA.

My make method:

```
public <R> R  make(Function<?, ?> ... tab) { // returning <R> R is okay?
    Function f = tab[0].apply(stringPathtoFile); // problem with stringPathtoFile
    for (int i = 1; i < tab.length; i++) {
        f = f.andThen(tab[i]);
    }
    return f; // problem after bad head of method
}
```

functionA need a file to work, functionB need functionA to work, functionC need function B to work, functionD need functionC to work...

I have problem with adding path to functionA and use andThen method (which should be good solution for that exercise)... Could you help me, please?

Exercise:

In file is a simply text, functionA is returning List of lines from file, functionB is connecting lines from list to one String, functionC is returning List of integers from that String, functionD is suming integers from List. I have body of that methods.

Comment: If it's an exercise, you should give a reference to this exercise.

Comment: okay, I fixed first post, at the end of it is description of exercise.

Comment: By using Function<?, ?>..., you lose all type safety. Don't do that. I don't really unerstand why you want your execute method to take several functions as argument. Just take one, and let the caller create a single function by composing several ones in a type-safe way.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not created that exercise. So, could you give me example of your words? Code: Integer a = new Execute<String>(pathToFile).make(functionA, functionB, functionC, functionD); must working... I know that it exercise can be stupid but I have to make it..

Comment: The thing is, we have no good idea of what the exercise is. Why don't you post it?

Comment: The exercise is in other language, I translate it end write in the end of first post. I have 4 methods and thats all, I want to induce it in other class by his method - make.

Comment: So, the instructions the teacher gave you are "I have body of that methods"?

Comment: Hmmm, I have only problem with my method make and array of function methods... Thats all... Bodies are mine but it is not a key of my question.

Comment: Passing an array doesn't make sense, since you need to pass 4 function of different types. But since you don't want to explain what you're supposed to do...

Comment: You seem to be confusing "function" and "application of function". `Function f = tab[0].apply(stringPathtoFile);`---here you _apply_ a function, but try to assign the result to a `Function`-typed variable. You should build your `andThen` chain first, then `return f.apply(stringPathtoFile)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you are the best.... it was my bad, thank you very much!